# Limit of $a_n = n\{\sqrt[n]{ea}-\sqrt[n]{a}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose $a \gt 0$

Evaluate limit of sequence

$$ a_n = n(\sqrt[n]{ea}-\sqrt[n]{a}), \ n \ge 1$$

My attempt :
I wrote sequence as $ a_n=n\ \sqrt[n]{a}\ (\sqrt[n]{e}-1)$ then I used expansion of $ e^x $ with $x=1/n$. So I get $\lim a^{1/n}(1+1/2n+....)$. This gives limit $=1$. I need suggestions here. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need suggestions when you have solved the problem ?

Comment: Mine was only a guess. I could have been wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you allowed to use? Set $\frac{1}{n} = t$ to get $\frac{e^t -1}{t} \to_t 1$

EDIT: this uses one of the definitions of log function: $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{a^t -1}{t} = \log a$

Comment: Nothing strict is allowed to use. Any reasonable way.

Comment: 'Nothing strict is allowed to use'-??

Comment: I m sorry, the questioner asked what methods are allowed to use. So I said any reasonable way can be used

Comment: 'reasonable' is too vague; different people find different things reasonable.

Comment: @BigBang: your answer doesn't bring any information.

Answer (score 0):

Let us do it the elementary way, only using the series expression of the exponential (i mean you have to somehow define $e$ to ask for the limit of this series, so i guess we can assume this):

As you already pointed out, it suffices to see $n(\exp(1/n)-1) \to 1$ once you know $a^{1/n} \to 1$ (This is a well known appliciation of Bernoulli's Inequality).

$n(\exp(1/n)-1)=n\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\frac{1}{n^k}}{k!} = 1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\frac{1}{n^{k-2}}}{k!} = 1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\frac{1}{n^k}}{(k+2)!}$.

We have to show that the latter summand converges to zero.

For that consider $0 \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\frac{1}{n^k}}{(k+2)!} \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(k+2)!}$. Since the latter series converges, this shows the assertion.